# (403) Your project does not have access to this feature when I call insert of Google_Service_Analytics_Profile object

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

It has been a long time since I am trying to implement server application which needs to insert view(profile) via php api but without success.

I have granted all the access to my service count email of the developer account in the account and property and view user management. I have made proper client object `$client` with all the proper keys and then here is my code:

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$profile = new Google_Service_Analytics_Profile($client);
$profile->setName('websiteView_0.1');
$profile->setECommerceTracking(True);

try {
  $analytics->management_profiles->insert('my_account_id', 'my_property_id', $profile);

} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

} catch (apiException $e) {
  print 'There was a general API error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is the Screenshot of my error. It would be great if I get proper guidance.

[image]

Comment: Never ever include screenshots of your error. 1. They are hard to read. 2. Search engines don't index them so others with similar problem won't find this post. Add the error message to the question!

Comment: I am reasonably sure that your need to specify a scope for your service object (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization?hl=en) if you want to get write access.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I have specified the scope already to 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit' but still :(

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you don't have beta access to this feature.

> [Account Management](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management)  Write operations in the Management API (e.g.
>   create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and
>   Goal resources is currently available as a developer preview in
>   limited beta. If you're interested in using these features,  [request
>   access to the beta](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xyjp6ca4YkGjh7TDi1Z3XyA3XHcRHkKzFentxzUrmPY/viewform).

If you have already applied you will need to wait until you hear from Google that you have been given access.  Last time I requested access it took more then a month you will hear from google if and when you get access.